# How do I work this Python slideshow script?

Tags: python, scripting, video-sequence-editor

I'm referring to the script located [here](https://gist.github.com/tin2tin/fd09d580eabc791700731497d6ca6916). This is what I've got:

```
import bpy
import os

def make_transition(seq, s1, s2):
    effect = seq.sequences.new_effect(name="Cross", channel=3, frame_start=s2.frame_final_start, frame_end=s1.frame_final_end, type='GAMMA_CROSS', seq1=s1, seq2=s2)


def create_slide_show(scn, dirname):

    if scn.sequence_editor is None:
        scn.sequence_editor_create()

    fr0 = 1
    nframes=60
    overlap = 15
    i=0
    prevStrip = None
    for basename in sorted(os.listdir(dirname)):
        if os.path.splitext(basename)[1] in {'.jpg', '.png', '.bmp', '.tif', '.exr'}:
            if 0 == i%2:
                ch = 1
            else:
                ch = 2
            strip = scn.sequence_editor.sequences.\
                new_image(name=basename,  filepath=os.path.join(dirname, basename), channel=ch, frame_start=fr0)
            strip.frame_final_duration = nframes+ overlap

            if prevStrip is not None:
                make_transition(scn.sequence_editor, prevStrip, strip)

            prevStrip = strip
            fr0 = fr0 + nframes
            i=i+1


create_slide_show(bpy.context.scene, "E:\\Jason\\Documents\\2020-01\\portfolio\\vapor_projection\\1080p")
```

I added the path on the last line, and modified the value of the nframes and overlap variables to suit my needs. In the text editor I hit Atl+p, the script runs, and nothing appears to happen. No errors generated. I've attached a screenshot below. Ignore the errors in the console, they are old errors from previous attempts.

[image: Blender screen shot]

I am not completely clueless on whats happening in the script. I can tell what certain lines of the code do, but I'm having trouble piecing it all together. One thing I don't understand is what seems to be a discrepancy between the names of the modules in the [Blender API Reference](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/), and the API calls (is this the correct terminology?) used in this script. This is the first time I've ever tried to do anything like this in Blender. I tried learning Python a few years ago, but didn't get too far.

Any help is much appreciated,

J.

Comment: Works here. Did you open the Sequencer(Video Editor) to see if the strips are generated? And if not, do your image files have extentions like this: '.jpg', '.png', '.bmp', '.tif', '.exr'?

Comment: OK, yeah the file extensions were in in all-caps (.JPG). I think that was the problem. I suppose this can be considered closed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can edit the question to mark is solved.